# How do I add 7 years to a current time expressed as a block.timestamp?

Tags: timestamp, time

Being new to solidity, I find the docs on the Internet very confusing. 
I simply want to add 7 years to a

```
uint timeInSevenYearsFromNow = (block.timestamp).add(????);
```

What is the value of `????` and how do I calculate it ? Is it 220898482 ?

Yes, this is a noob question.  I do not care how precise or exact it will be when executed, whether it is off by a nano-second or several minutes.

Comment: Do you care about leap seconds/years?

Comment: @TjadenHess not at all, I just want to express it all as digits, without using "days" or * operators... only a simple addition of numbers. Thanks ! Edit: thanks for the answer, but I am just curious about 220898482...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `days` and `*`? It's more readable and adds zero cost since the constants get expanded out at compile time

Comment: I want to add a prime number, just for fun ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are OK with being overly simplistic and ignoring leap seconds and leap years, you can simply do

```
uint timeInSevenYearsFromNow = now + 7 * 365 days;
```

In older versions of solidity you could use `years` as a unit, but this was depreciated due to the complexity of accurately tracking time over long periods.

Comment: so is the 7*365 days actually 220898482 (or some other very close number) ?

Comment: Yes, the unit is just syntactic sugar for (365  * number of seconds in a day)

Comment: @TjadenHess How about it I cared about the leap seconds and leap years. How would I calculate this?

Comment: @TjadenHess How would I go about this if I DID care about leap seconds and leap years?